# how to create firebase recyclerview for list inside another list

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

so i am trying with this application and the database looks something like that 
[image]

i successfuly grabed that data that is child to `mental` and i created recyclerview with it(description,endedat,startedat,title)

so how can i create a recyclerview from the list inside each item list 
[image]

what i could get is only the child pushed key by using

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("records").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("mental).orderByKey().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Iterator<DataSnapshot>i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                    if(i.hasNext()){
                        Log.v("keys",i.next().getKey());
                    }
                }
```

beside i tried to add an array of corrisponding class in viewholder but didnt work too

Comment: Nothing in your code snippet uses arrays, adapters or FirebaseUI. As it stands there is a lot of ground to cover between the code you shared and the problem you are trying to solve. A large part of that ground is already covered in the [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database).

Comment: that's exactly what i said i can do it .. what i cant and what i am asking is how to make the list inside the list not the main one..how to access second level randomed value

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i successfuly added list showing (description,endedat,startedat,title) but the inner list that contains (name,endedat,startedat,ppd,special) that is the one i can't implement